# Django 1.10 Templates - Print two python lists next to eachother in HTML Template

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I am currently querying my test legacy database for all objects with value `oee_hour` which are not null using:

```
lines_hourly = Lineoeex.objects.all.values('oee_hour')
hourly_oee_list = list (Lineoeex.objects.all().values_list('oee_hour', flat=True).exclude(oee_hour=None)) #no null entries
```

In the same row, my database also contains a `date_hour` column, also containing null values.

I am querying for all objects with value `date_hour` using:

```
time_hourly = Lineoeex.objects.all.values('date_hour')
time_hourly_list = list (Lineoeex.objects.all().values_list('date_hour', flat=True).exclude(date_hour=None))
```

**Both lists match, with 1 real value followed by 5 null values**

I am then passing on these variables on to my template.

I am iterating over the `hourly_oee_list` in my HTML code and printing each value.

*How do I print the `date_hour` values from the `time_hourly_list` next to the hourly_oee?*

### Code to print hourly_oee

```
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for hourlyoee in hourly_oee_list %}
        <li class="list-group-item> OEE: {{ hourlyoee }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This prints out all the `oee_hour` values in the `hourly_oee_list`. I want to print out the `date_hour` values inside `time_hourly_list` right next to the OEE values with the same stylings.

Nesting the for loops does not give the desired effect.

Any suggesionts on how this can be implemented? thanks

Comment: Are the elements in both queries the same?

Comment: Why are you querying two separate lists anyway?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Elements are different. One contains the actual OEE value, the other contains the time it was read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given I understood it correctly, you can combine the two queries, this not only provides a *guarantee* that the data in the two lists are in the same order, which will make it more efficient as well:

```
data = Lineoeex.objects.filter(
    oee_hour__isnull=False,
    date_hour__isnull=False,
).values_list('oee_hour', 'date_hour')
```

`data` is here a `QuerySet` that contains 2-tuples, we can then iterate over the queryset and use *sequence unpacking* to access the values with:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for oeee, datehour in data %}
        <li class="list-group-item> OEE: {{ oeee}} - {{ datehour }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If however the number of columns is reasonable, and it does not take much time to parse the results, it is usually simpler to fetch the `Lineoeex` objects, and access the attributes directly, for example:

```
data = Lineoeex.objects.filter(
    oee_hour__isnull=False,
    date_hour__isnull=False,
)
```

and in the template:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for datum in data %}
        <li class="list-group-item> OEE: {{ datum.oee_hour}} - {{ datum.date_hour }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This makes it more explicit what attributes you are using from the `Lineoeex` objects: you do not need to inspect the `QuerySet` in the view, to understand how it interacts with the template.

Comment: Thanks, tested first method and works well. Last remaining issue is how to manipulate the variable datehour such that I can write for example OEE is 80% from Hour `10` to hour `11`. Template rendering such as {{datehour+1}} won't work. In my previous method I used to manipulate this variable in the `views.py` and pass both the `datehour` and `datehour+1` to the template. Can something similar be done from the template side? Thanks

Comment: @fcp: with a template filter, so `{{ datehour|add:"1" }}` will add one to the result (given it is a number, if it is a `DateTime` or anything related, you should manipulate it in the *view*.

Answer (score 2):

```
hourly_oee_list = Lineoeex.objects.values('oee_hour', 'date_hour').exclude(date_hour=None, oee_hour=None)


<ul class="list-group">
    {% for hourlyoee in hourly_oee_list %}
        <li class="list-group-item> OEE: {{ hourlyoee.oee_hour }} </li>
        <li class="list-group-item> OEE: {{ hourlyoee.date_hour }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```